# Given two classes, creating an object of each class in one another results in StackOverflow Exception

Tags: java, object, project-management

Given two classes, creating an object of each class in one another results in StackOverflow Exception. It is a JAVA project btw.

There are multiple classes in my projects and for using the other classes, I thought i would create objects of the other class and use it.

Say i have class Main and class GUI. I have created object of GUI in MAIN and initialized it. Similarly i have created an object of MAIN in GUI and initialized it.

Now this gives me a Stack Overflow Exception as the the constructor calls are going deep into recursion.

How do i go about it?

One possible solution i can think of is making variables and methods of one class STATIC.

Any other solution? Please suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be passing an instance of one of you classes into the constructor of the other class.

```
public class Main {
   private final GUI gui;
   Main() {
      gui = new GUI(this);
   }
}

public class GUI {
   private final Main main;
   public GUI(Main main) {
      this.main = main;
   }
}
```

You could also use setters instead of constructors.  I don't like this option as much, because you lose the ability to make your variables final.

```
public class Main {
   private GUI gui;
   Main() {
   }
   public void setGui(GUI gui) {
      this.gui = gui;
   }
}

public class GUI {
   private Main main;
   public GUI() {
   }
   public void setMain(Main main) {
      this.main = main;
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Main main = new Main();
   GUI gui = new GUI();
   main.setGui(gui);
   gui.setMain(main);
}
```

Comment: This is correct, although it's also the case that you should generally make methods static when they don't access any local information - and, as Jigar Joshi noted below, it can make sense to make it a singleton class if you only really need one of it across your entire application.

Comment: but then i have a third class RecieveThread that accesses the GUI class. I need an object there too. So adding the Main parameter wont work.

Comment: @AbhishekNandgaonkar You can add a GUI object to the constructor of RecieveThread.  If the relationship gets complicated enough, you may want to use create all the classes without instances to each other, and then create setters that will initialize each one.  Then one piece of code that constructs all the options and calls all the setters.

Comment: @AbhishekNandgaonkar see edit for example of using setters (not settlers)

Comment: This is a very well explained answer. Circular references can be very dangerous when implemented incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton ? (if it works for your app )